# Problem with DIVs not lining up correctly

Tags: css

I am trying very hard to make this work but I can't see what is wrong. I have the following code:

```
<div id="ftr_btm">
        <div id="ftr_ctr">
            <div id="ftr_msg">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">123</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ftr_rgt">
            <div id="ftr_msg">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">ABC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#ftr_btm { height:24px; margin:0 auto; border-top: 1px solid #AAA;
    background: #F6F6F6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%, #F6F6F6 5%, #F0F0F0 6%, #F0F0F0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F6F6F6), color-stop(5%,#F6F6F6), color-stop(6%,#F0F0F0), color-stop(100%,#F0F0F0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%,#F6F6F6 5%,#F0F0F0 6%,#F0F0F0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%,#F6F6F6 5%,#F0F0F0 6%,#F0F0F0 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%,#F6F6F6 5%,#F0F0F0 6%,#F0F0F0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F6F6F6', endColorstr='#F0F0F0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%,#F6F6F6 5%,#F0F0F0 6%,#F0F0F0 100%); /* W3C */ }
#ftr_btm p { line-height:20px; text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:0px; color:#666; }

/* Footer Message */
#ftr_ctr {text-align: center; font-size:0.8em; }
#ftr_rgt {text-align: right; font-size:0.8em; top: 0px; position: relative;}
#ftr_msg { color:#666;  display: inline-block; padding-top: 2px; height:24px; background: transparent;}
#ftr_msg ul { margin: 0; }
#ftr_msg ul li { float: left; overflow: inherit;position:relative; white-space: nobox; display:inline; line-height: 20px; }
#ftr_msg ul li a { color:#666; display:inline; padding: 0 10px; white-space: nobox; text-decoration: none; }
#ftr_msg ul li a:hover { color:#3985d4;}
```

The problem is that 123 and ABC are both supposed to appear within the footer. When I run it with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Gar/) then you can see ABC is BELOW the footer. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong. I checked many times and still cannot see what's wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Do you want the text in the footer? that is all? What are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: The ABC and 123 are both supposed to be inside the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing your intent from what you have so far..

- On `#ftr_rgt`, you need to set `position` to `absolute`, instead of `relative`.
- On the parent of `#ftr_rgt` (which is `#ftr_btm`, you need to set `position: relative`.
- Lastly, you need to add `right: 0` to `#ftr_rgt`. You already have `top: 0`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/a4Gar/1/

If you're trying to use `relative`/`absolute` positioning, you need to get your head around how it works:

http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Lastly, I think that you could accomplish this layout in a simpler way with `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem - block-level elements like divs will *not* appear next to each other unless you change the way they're displayed.  Currently, `#ftr_ctr` is taking up the entire footer, and `#ftr_rgt` is appearing below it.
There are a couple ways to move `#ftr_rgt` up.  Since it has `position:relative;`, you can give it a `top:-20px;` to slide it up.  The downside it that it'll still reserve white space for itself below the footer.

You can make both `#ftr_ctr` and `#ftr_rgt` `float:left;`, and put a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after them.  You'll need to adjust the widths of each of them to get them to line up right, though.

You can set both of them to have `display:inline-block;`

You may even be able to get away with just using  `display:inline` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ftr_rgt {
    text-align: right;
    font-size:0.8em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="ftr_btm">
    <div id="ftr_ctr">
        <div id="ftr_msg">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ftr_rgt">
        <div id="ftr_msg">
            <ul>
             <li><a href="/">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="/"></a></li>
                <li><a href="/">ABC</a></li>
                <li><a href="/"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This might be what you are looking for, but I do not know exactly how you want the text formatted.